# How to enable reminder in my android app

Tags: android, notifications

I am doing reminder in my application.

I have to search the events for current date in my local database and raise the alarm.

How can I do this reminder functionality?

Comment: Just run eclipse and write some code. Make your question more atomic and do some research befor writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**AlarmManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to implement the reminders in your application.

Step 1 : Create a **`BroadcastReceiver`** which listens for the broadcast messages.

Step 2 : Create a `PendingIntent` and set it with the `AlarmManager`.

Step 3 : Show the reminder/notification in the `BroadcastReceiver` when the broadcast is received, i.e. `onReceive()`

Refer this [tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) for further explanations.